# How to Hide the welcome screen when user have ever open the android apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native

I just learn about android, and i decide to make my 'serious' apps (code for business).

I make my apps to have a welcome screen like this

[The very first page of welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmq7r.png)

[The last page of welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCGgS.png)

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egevx.png)

In the last page of welcome screen, it have finish button to show the Main Activity.
The problem is, when user close the apps and open the apps (again), the welcome screen always show up (i want the welcome screen not to be shown again).

So the question is, 
**How to hide the welcome screen when user have ever open the apps?**

or maybe this question is more simpler (in sentence structure) **How to make the welcome screen just appear in the first time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the welcome activity, you may store some state which records that a user has already seen this welcome content.  Shared preferences are a good option for this.  In the click handler for the finish button, record that the user has completed the welcome activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("welcome", true).apply();
```

Then, in the start of the welcome activity, you may check for this state.  If the user has already completed the welcome content, you may forward to another activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean visited = prefs.getBoolean("welcome");
if (visited) {
    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me a lot and solve my problem. Once again, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Well in your app you most likely use `setContentView(r.layout.welcome)`
an easy way is to use shared preferences to check wether a user has already opend the app. then just add an if clause

to write SharedPreferences use:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("has_visited", true).commit();
```